# Drag image from a browser window to a file input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developed a file input, is there a way to drag an image from a browser window into an input?

Can someone help me to create an event that when dragging an image to an input allows me to get the image?

At this point I managed to create an event by obtaining the image using ctrl-v but would it be possible to obtain it through Drag & Drop from a browser window?

Thank you !

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pt6ysm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

```
   <div class="drop">
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="desc">
            drop / paste here your images
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc">
        <img class="img-responsive drag" style="border-radius: 8px;">
    </div>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
   </div>
```

Comment: check this link, it can help you, https://medium.com/@mariemchabeni/angular-7-drag-and-drop-simple-file-uploadin-in-less-than-5-minutes-d57eb010c0dc  it uses HostBinding and HostListener.

Comment: @Slow 
Thanks, I already tested this example but when I drag an image from the browser it doesn't detect :(

Comment: are you using the demo as a template? if yes i added an answer below, it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked ur demo and you already have @HostListener("paste", ["$event"])
 onPaste ().

You can add this :

```
 @HostListener("dragover", ["$event"]) public onDragOver(evt: DragEvent) {
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
this.background = "#999"; }

@HostListener("dragleave", ["$event"]) public onDragLeave(evt: DragEvent) {
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
this.background = "#eee"; }

@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public onDrop(evt: DragEvent) {
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
this.background = '#eee';

let files: FileHandle[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < evt.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
  const file = evt.dataTransfer.files[i];
  const url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
  files.push({ file, url });
}
if (files.length > 0) {
  this.files.emit(files);
}  }
```

In your html you should add an appDrag (files)="filesDropped($event).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I tried to implement but some errors appeared, can you post a demo? Thank you so much again

Comment: it should help you out  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-and-drop-upload?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Strange, I tried to drag images from the browser to the input and did several console.log () and nothing was detected :(

Comment: can you put your code on stackblitz, i can take a look or post the exact error you are receiving

Comment: I used your stackblitz example and nothing happens when I drag the image, not even with console.log ... it seems that the functions are not executed ... does the same happen to you?

Comment: I already got to execute, but the filelist comes = 0 when I drag the image :(

Comment: yes the example on stackblitz works perfect, i just dragged and drop an image on it right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207536/discussion-between-slow-and-mike-landers).

Answer (score -1):

In your input must to have an **ondrop** event, like this:

```html
<input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*" ondrop="here_your_function()" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work ... when you drag the image it tries to open in another window :(